# Как восстановить файлы, которые удалены с помощью команды git clean -fdx?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

Всем привет!
Нашла команду здесь, в стеке, и не дочитав информацию о том, что она удаляет все файлы, которые не отслеживаются и игнорятся, ввела ее в терминал..
Думала удалить один файл, но удалилась папка target и ignore list, которые удалять не нужно было.
Большая просьба, если восстановить есть возможность, пожалуйста, подскажите как!

Comment: через git восстановить их нельзя, т.к. они не отслеживались. но вполне возможно что можно восстановить через `Local History` в самой `Intellij IDEA`. При этом содержимое папки `target` и так постоянно переписывается при сборке проекта. Так что ничего страшногов этом нет.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, если они у меня на GitHub оставить, я могу сделать pull, или они все равно не восстановятся?

Comment: С IDEA поняла, если не получится, вручную можно же восстановить? Кроме target

Comment: если они остались на github, то их естественно можно восстановить.

Comment: Через Local History удалось восстановить скрытые файлы в проекте, также восстановила target, а может еще знаете, папка test как восстанавливается? Она тоже удалилась.

Comment: А у вас тесты в ней были?

Comment: Нет, тестов не было.

Comment: еще можно восстановить через машину времени, если у вас макось, ну или если другая ось и у нее есть похожая система постоянного бэкапа.